# NavigationLink pops out upon List update ONLY when List is not scrolled to the top

Tags: swift, swiftui

Apologies if the title is confusing. So, I'm implementing a chat app where there's a list of `ChatRow`s that would, upon clicking, entering into a `MessageView`. When a user sends a message, the list of `ChatRow`s may reorder because I order them in a way such that ones contain the latest messages are placed on the top.

The code looks roughly like this (let me know if more detail is needed):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var chatsManager: ChatsManager
    @EnvironmentObject var messagesManager: MessagesManager

     var body: some View {
         NavigationView{
             VStack{
                 // Some Views
                 VStack{
                     if chatsManager.chats.isEmpty{
                      Text("you have no chats for now").frame(maxHeight:.infinity, alignment: .top)
                     }
                     else {
                         List() {
                             ForEach($chatsManager.chats, id: \.id){ $chat in
                                 NavigationLink (destination:
                                           MessageView(chat: chat)
                                           .onAppear{messagesManager.fetchMessages(from: chat.id)}
                                 ){ ChatRow(chat: $chat) }
                             }
                     }.listStyle(.plain)
                 }
             }
         }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
             
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            
     }
}
```

A very weird thing is that, if I click into chats that are within the viewport when `List` is scrolled to the top, everything would work perfectly (no auto popping-back, the `List` is updated properly when manually popped back).

But if I scroll down the list when the top few `ChatRow`s get scrolled away from the screen, I get popped back if I send any messages.

What I learned from searching the web was that `List` lazy loads elements, so that might be the cause of the problem. But I couldn't figure out a way to solve it.

### Code to reproduce the problem

Just copy the following into one file and run.

Observe how things behave differently when you click into the first chat and click the button vs clicking into the last chat and click the button.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct DebugView: View {
    
    @StateObject var chatsManager = ChatsManager()
    
     var body: some View {
         NavigationView{
             VStack{
                 HStack {
                 Text("Chats")
                 }.padding()
                 VStack{
                         List() {
                             ForEach($chatsManager.chats, id: \.id){ $chat in
                                         NavigationLink (destination:
                                                   ChatDetailView(chat: chat)
                                 ){ DemoChatRow(chat: $chat) }}

                     }.listStyle(.plain)
             }
         }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
             
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
             .environmentObject(chatsManager)
     }
}


struct DemoChatRow: View {
    @Binding var chat: Chat
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(chat.name)
            Text(chat.lastMessageTimeStamp, style: .time)
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
    }
}


struct ChatDetailView: View {
    var chat: Chat
    @EnvironmentObject var chatsManager: ChatsManager
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            chatsManager.updateDate(for: chat.id)
        } ) {
            Text("Click to update the current chat to now")
        }
    }
}



class ChatsManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var chats = [
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 1", name: "GroupChat 1", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 2", name: "GroupChat 2", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 3", name: "GroupChat 3", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 4", name: "GroupChat 4", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 5", name: "GroupChat 5", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 6", name: "GroupChat 6", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 7", name: "GroupChat 7", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 8", name: "GroupChat 8", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 9", name: "GroupChat 9", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat 10", name: "GroupChat 10", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat2 5", name: "GroupChat2 5", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat2 6", name: "GroupChat2 6", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat2 7", name: "GroupChat2 7", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat2 8", name: "GroupChat2 8", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat2 9", name: "GroupChat2 9", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date()),
        Chat(id: "GroupChat2 10", name: "GroupChat2 10", lastMessageTimeStamp: Date())].sorted(by: {$0.lastMessageTimeStamp.compare($1.lastMessageTimeStamp) == .orderedDescending})
    
    func updateDate(for chatID: String) {
        if let idx = chats.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == chatID}) {
            self.chats[idx] = Chat(id: chatID, name: self.chats[idx].name, lastMessageTimeStamp: Date())
         }
        self.chats.sort(by: {$0.lastMessageTimeStamp.compare($1.lastMessageTimeStamp) == .orderedDescending})
    }
    
        
}




struct Chat: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var lastMessageTimeStamp: Date
    
    static func == (lhs: Chat, rhs: Chat) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

}


struct DebugView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DebugView().environmentObject(ChatsManager())
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [mre], this will be challenging to help debug

Comment: @jnpdx thanks. I'm working on it, and will update the post.

Comment: @jnpdx updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that this relates to the fact that the `List` lazily loads elements -- once the `NavigationLink` is off the screen, if the `Chat` element changes, the `View` ends up getting popped off the stack.

The standard solution to this is to add a hidden `NavigationLink` to your hierarchy that has an `isActive` property that controls whether or not it is active or not. Unfortunately, it requires a little more boilerplate code than the convenient list element binding that was introduced in Swift 5.5.

Your code might look something like this:

```
struct DebugView: View {
    
    @StateObject var chatsManager = ChatsManager()
    @State private var activeChat : String?
    
    private func activeChatBinding(id: String?) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init {
            activeChat != nil && activeChat == id
        } set: { newValue in
            activeChat = newValue ? id : nil
        }
    }
    
    private func bindingForChat(id: String) -> Binding<Chat> {
        .init {
            chatsManager.chats.first { $0.id == id }!
        } set: { newValue in
            chatsManager.chats = chatsManager.chats.map { $0.id == id ? newValue : $0 }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    Text("Chats")
                }.padding()
                VStack{
                    List() {
                        ForEach($chatsManager.chats, id: \.id) { $chat in
                            Button(action: {
                                activeChat = chat.id
                            }) {
                                DemoChatRow(chat: $chat)
                            }
                        }
                    }.listStyle(.plain)
                }
                .background {
                    NavigationLink("", isActive: activeChatBinding(id: activeChat)) {
                        if let activeChat = activeChat {
                            ChatDetailView(chat: bindingForChat(id: activeChat).wrappedValue)
                        } else {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .environmentObject(chatsManager)
    }
}
```

*Note: I kept the `Binding` that you have to `DemoChatRow` even though it looks like it's just a one-way connection here in the demo code, making the assumption that in your real code, you need two-way communication there*

Comment: Thank you that worked very well! And yes, your assumption is correct -- my real code would be a two-way comm that affects how the view is rendered.

Comment: Could you briefly explain the logic of your solution?

Comment: The logic is that if you include a `NavigationLink` as a background to your `View`, it'll always be in the hierarchy and won't get loaded/unloaded like the `List` elements do. To interact with it programmatically, you have to use the `isActive` property which is controlled by a `Binding<Bool>`. `activeChatBinding` converts from a `id : String` to the `Binding<Bool>` that `isActive` expects. `bindingForChat` provides a binding based on the item's id back to the original array.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense and is brilliant! Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from @jnpdc works, you lose all `NavigationLink` features, like the selected state etc.

A simple fix for this is to wrap your `List` in a `ScrollViewReader`, and maintain the scroll position in the background. Simply observe the active object and when it changes, scroll to the object's `id`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var chatsManager: ChatsManager

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List {
                    // list content
                }
                .onChange(of: chatsManager.activeChat, perform: { _ in
                    proxy.scrollTo(loc.internalName, anchor: .center)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. This issue is solved in any case with the iOS 16 APIs.